# R SOAP passing parameters and printing

Tags: r, xml, web-services, soap

```
    library(RCurl)

    headerFields =
    c(Accept = "text/xml",
    Accept = "multipart/*",
    'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    SOAPAction = "XYZ")

    body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="XYZ" xmlns:xsd="XYZ" 
   xmlns:soap="XYZ/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
   <clientLogin xmlns="XYZ">
   <id>string</id>
   </clientLogin>
   </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>'

   curlPerform(url = "XYZ",
                          httpheader = headerFields,
                          postfields = body
                          )
```

I am using the above code to get data for each ID that I pass in the body section. I replace the string in "string" with IDs like 4AD,H5F etc

1. How can I create a loop to pass a list of IDs into the soap request instead of having to manually enter the ID for each request.
2. How can I get the output from :

   ```
   curlPerform(url = "XYZ",
                         httpheader = headerFields,
                         postfields = body)
   ```

and parse it in a file/ append it each time I call a new ID

Comment: Well, your body is just a string and you can build (concatenate) strings with with `paste()` function. Not sure what the response looks like so no idea how you want it "parsed" but there are lots of functions to write to files in R. Did you try to write your own code to solve these problems? Perhaps share what you tried and describe exactly how it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you MrFlick. I was getting the below error when trying to use the write_xml function -write_xml(result,Output.xml, options = as_xml_document())

Error- no applicable method for 'write_xml' applied to an object of class "c('XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument')"

But later i tried saveXML and i am ablt to print the xml objects

Comment: I am still facing issues with creating a loop and extracting data for a set of ID values. I will revise and improve the question and post it again soon